# If I include a mib in snmp view ? Only that included mib will be available for polling,?

Tags: snmp, router, net-snmp

I am new to SNMP.
I am having a doubt in snmp view configuration in router.
What all the mibs will be included by default for polling in snmp v3 ?
If I include a mib in snmp view ? Only that included mib will be available for polling? All the other mibs will not be able to poll ?

Comment: Yes, only included mib can be polled.

Answer (score 0):

The **SNMP VACM** subsystem of SNMPv3 is designed to **restrict access to certain MIB tree branches**. So yes your assumptions are correct.